# I want to get a distinct list of values for three variables that add up to 1 in increments of 0.05

Tags: math, combinations, equation-solving

What I want is to find a distinct list of decimals that add to 1 given that I'm using three variables and each variable can increase by 0.05.

The table of values would look something like this:

```
Var1   Var2   Var3   Total
 0.0    0.05   0.95   1
 0.20   0.40   0.40   1
 0.15   0.75   0.10   1
 0.50   0.25   0.25   1
 0.80   0.20   0.00   1
```

And so on... I think you get the idea.

Comment: What language do you want to do this in?

Comment: I was thinking in Excel, but I have SQL (Teradata SQL Assistant), SAS, and R downloaded on my machine which I'm capable enough to use.

Comment: Do you want to consider, for example (0.05, 0.45, 0.50) as distinct from or identical to (0.45, 0.50, 0.05)?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to realize is that since they all sum to 1, `var3` is a function of `var2 + var1`. So you really have two variables here.

You can brute force this by just looping `var1` and `var2` blindly and keeping the values:

```
List<int[]> sets = new ArrayList<>();

for(int var1 = 0; var1 <= 100; var1 += 5) {
    for(int var2 = 0; var2 <= 100; var2 += 5) {
        int var3 = 100 - (var1 + var2);
        if(var1 + var2 + var3 == 100 && (var1 != var2) && (var1 != var3) && (var2 != var3)) {
             int[] set = new int[] { var1, var2, var3 };
             sets.add(set);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is riddled with inefficiencies that hopefully you can spot and optimize, but this should be an effective way to do it. Note that I used integers so we didn't end up with weird floating point rounding errors. Modify your output accordingly.

Comment: Sorry what language is this in? I tried R and Python but haven't been able to figure it out. I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: Figured out how to do this, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: This was in Java but the algorithm would be the same in any language